# Index Match? Or some other function?

Tags: google-sheets

‘Student Needs’! Columns I through O contain information on when each student attends an intervention class. Intervention classes take place during the second half of the classes (Science or social studies) or during the second half of Co-taught classes (math or ELA). Science and social studies interventions are done on either Monday/Wednesday or Tuesday/Friday (Thursdays have a special schedule that we do not need to consider). Math and ELA interventions occur on all four days.

In ‘Student Master’!, each student’s schedule is listed for both MW and TF. In Columns E, G, K, and M, I would like to populate any of the interventions that are listed in the ‘Student Needs’! sheet. For instance, Lindsey Lukowski has Social Skills on MW2 (Mondays and Wednesdays 2nd hour).  So in cell ‘Student Master’! G31 should return “Social Skills”.

William Watters is getting Read Naturally and Reading Comp during his 5th Hour Co-Taught ELA. So ‘Student Master’! K51 and K52 should both return Read Naturally & Reading Comp (in the same cell).

Here is the workbook:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aW7ExATzMn9Rf8IFLI4v-CQiqsXnxyDm8PxqMW999bY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My understanding is that Excel and GSheets process Index -Match in similar fashions, so someone from either community could probably answer the question. I am also considering switching to Office 365, in which case would require me to use excel to perform the same function.

Comment: I am not fixed on Index/ Match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complex functions that seems to do what you want. I have tested it in a copy of your sheet

Just Change **E$2** for different columns.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Student Needs'!"&CHAR(72+IFERROR(MATCH("HR "&E$2,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("'Student Needs'!I"&REGEXEXTRACT($A3,"[0-9]+")+5&":N"&REGEXEXTRACT($A3,"[0-9]+")+5),"[A-Z ]+[0-9]")),0),MATCH($C3,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("'Student Needs'!I"&REGEXEXTRACT($A3,"[0-9]+")+5&":N"&REGEXEXTRACT($A3,"[0-9]+")+5),"[A-Z]+")),0)))&5))
```

Also I am not sure where "6- Science" should go? Is this also HR 6?

---

In order for it to work with actual

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Student Needs'!"&CHAR(72+IFERROR(MATCH("HR "&E$2,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("'Student Needs'!I"&ROW(VLOOKUP($A3,'Student Needs'!$A$1:$B,2,false))&":N"&ROW(VLOOKUP($A3,'Student Needs'!$A$1:$B,2,false))),"[A-Z ]+[0-9]")),0),MATCH($C3,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("'Student Needs'!I"&ROW(VLOOKUP($A3,'Student Needs'!$A$1:$B,2,false))&":N"&ROW(VLOOKUP($A3,'Student Needs'!$A$1:$B,2,false))),"[A-Z]+")),0)))&5))
```

Comment: Hi Akshin,
Your answer works great until I moved it to my original sheet. I think the issue has something to do with "[0-9]+"  because the actual students do not have numeral suffixes. I tried taking out the "[0-9]+" but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas? I am just starting to delve into reexextract and indirect.
Thanks!

Comment: Check my updated answer. This should work with names and student numbers as it gets the exact match from column A.

Comment: Hi Akshin,
I may need to clarify a little bit.

Comment: Each hour is split into two parts. In part "A" (1A, 2A, 5A,6A) everyone in the class participates. In part "B", some students are pulled out for extra help. To complicate things further, the students will only be pulled out on alternating days - Monday/Wednesday (MW) or Tuesday/Friday (TF). So on Student Needs, I have when the extra help class is taking place (example: "TF1" means Tuesday/Friday during hour 1). I need the TF# and MW# pull out class names (Writing, Read Naturally, Comprehension, Wilson, etc) pulled to the Student Master sheet for the hour that they will occur.

Comment: Another complication is that sometimes I will be teaching the first part of the class, and the extra help becomes integrated into the Co-teaching (Co-T), so when students have HR 5 Co-T in Student Needs, the Student Master cell for 5B needs to state the extra help class as well. So there are really two categories to cover. TF#/MW#  and HR # Co-T. Co-Taught extra help occurs on TF and MW days.

Comment: Ok, I am completely confused at this stage. So "B" part should only pull cells which have MW/TF ? Please Edit your initial question and give as much details as you can, because this is different from what is in the question. If you could provide some examples as well that would be helpful.